# How to access an object form another function

Tags: javascript, function, object

i wanna get access to localVariable form another function

(sorry about grammar English is not my main language)

the code:

```
let Info = {}
function storeInfo(Info) {
    let name;
    let age;
    function getName() {
        name = prompt('enter your name:')
    }
    function getAge() {
        age = prompt('how old are you?')
    }
    getName();
    getAge(); 
    Info = {
        name:name,
        age:age,
    }

    returnInfo(Info)
}

storeInfo(Info)

function returnInfo(Info) {
    return Info.name + ' ' + Info.age;
}
let result = returnInfo(Info);
alert(result)
```

i wanna returnInfo function get the info of storeInfo function and alert it and the end

Comment: You'd have to assign to the properties directly, not assign a new object to `Info`. E.g. `Info.name = name; Info.age = age;`. But why not simply return an object from `getInfo`? That would make much more sense.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for your response. i`m new in javascript and i want use more concept to learn them. yes the better way is to directly assign them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified it for you because you made a lot of mess.

1. Put the functions as first in code, it will be more clear.
2. Try not to mix functions with executable code at the learning stage.
3. To use function in function better is to learn about `classes`.

Simplified code:

```
    function storeInfo() {
      let localFuncInfo = {
        name:prompt('enter your name:'),
        age:prompt('how old are you?'),
      }
      return localFuncInfo;
    }
    
    function returnInfo(Info) {
      return Info.name + ' ' + Info.age;
    }

    let Info = storeInfo() ;
    let result = returnInfo(Info);
    
    alert(result);
```